# In Higgs context, do false vacuum hypothesis imply that true vacuum is *higher* (not lower)?

Tags: energy, vacuum, higgs, symmetry-breaking

In *theories* of false vacuum for Higgs potential, the Higgs field would be currently in an instable false vacuum and would later evolve in a true vacuum, with a lower potential value.

Would this true vacuum be *necessary* characterized by a higher value of the Higgs field?

I would expect so, since in this hypothetic theory, at the early universe, the Higgs field was 0, so I would not see how the true vacuum value of field *could* be lower to the *current* value of vaccum, else in the Higgs field evolution towards the false vacuum, the field would have already encountered the "true vacuum", so it could not evolve to a false vacuum that has a field value higher to the true vacuum.

If so, why do theories of false vacuum give in their schematic a true vacuum *lower* (at the left) to the false vacuum: this looks impossible in the scenario of evolution of universe.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum

Comment: what? that's what "false vacuum" means.

Comment: My question is equivalent : "do you confirm that the Higgs field could only be *higher* when arriving in the false vacuum and could not be *lower*", while wikipedia shows an example with the *reverse situation*.